# Merge three array into a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have merged 2 arrays in to a customized string. Now I am trying to merge 3 array but that doesn't came as expected.

**2 Arrays**

```
         A = ['Name' , 'Age'];
         B = ['abc',10];

         [A, B].reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) =>
                  v + " is " + b[i]  + "\n"
                ))
```

**O/P**

```
["Name is abc","Age is 10"]
```

**3 Arrays**

```
         A = ['Name' , 'Age'];
         B = ['is' , 'is'];
         C = ['abc',10];

         [A, B].reduce((a, b,c) => a.map((v, i) =>
                  v + b[i] + " " +c[i]  + "\n"
                ))
```

I am getting too many `undefined` value with this. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: `A = [Name , Age];
         B = [is , is];
         C = [abc,10];` Can you show where you define those 4 variables?

Comment: `[A, B].reduce`

Comment: You need to define variables before you use them - show where `Name`, `Age`, `Is`, and `abc` are defined (do those contain strings corresponding to their variable names?)

Comment: I think `[Name , Age]` is supposed to be `["Name" , "Age"]` - it's not *variables* but these are all strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map()` on one of the array and then get the values of corresponding index from other two arrays. Use `join()` to get a main string

```js
let A = ['Name', 'Age'];
let B = ['is', 'is'];
let C = ['abc', 10];

const res = A.map((x, i) => x + ' ' + B[i] + ' ' + C[i]).join('\n');
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the `reduce` on one array and access the other arrays by index. Here is slight changes to your code.

```js
A = ["Name", "Age"];
B = ["is", "is"];
C = ["abc", 10];
const res = A.reduce(
  (acc, curr, i) => (acc.push(curr + " " + B[i] + " " + C[i] + "\n"), acc),
  []
);

console.log(res);
```